# Can't type password for SSH in Powershell

Tags: ssh, opengl, vnc-viewer, ngrok

I would like to render an animation in Blender program over Google Colaboratory and I followed this tutorial to help me do that https://internet-of-tomohiro.netlify.app/google_colab/vnc.en.html. So basically, google colab's virtual machine should connect to my ngrok account and I needed SSH to connect to the server and to do that. I installed SSH using Scoop. Then I typed following command in Powershell: 'ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o VisualHostKey=yes -p 11458 -L 5901:localhost:5901 colab@2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io'. Then Powershell asked me to type colab@2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io's password. I copied password from google colaba and pasted it in Powershell but nothing showed up, like I didn't even type anything. I tried manually typing but still nothing showed up. I tried pasting password again and typed enter. Powershell responded with: Permission denied, please try again.. I tried 2 more times and then it said 'colab@2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io: Permission denied (publickey,password)'.

Why won't it let me to type password, I can't do any further steps without typing the password? Every step I did is provided in the link above.

Link on how to run SSH server: https://github.com/demotomohiro/remocolab

Comment: Can you provide the verbose logs?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for asking but what's that and how can I get it?

Comment: The Verbose logging for the OpenSSH service?

Comment: Where's that stored?

Comment: You are aware that it is normal for SSH to not display any characters indicating that you are typing in a password, correct? That still doesn't explain why a pasted password doesn't work, but you need to know that SSH will not show you an indication of a password being typed.

Comment: @SamForbis I was aware of that but still I was puzzled why it constantly denies access even though the password is correct.

Comment: @DinoGržinić - You have to enable verbose logging.

Comment: @Ramhound How do you do that?

Comment: Have you done research on how to enable OpenSSH verbose logging?

Comment: @Ramhound Never mind! I solved the problem using the public key so I don't need to type the password! Still thank you for trying to help!